# What is the function of the Name attribute of ReportGroupRequest in ReportsRequest method

Tags: metatrader4

The ReportsRequest method is documented as "Request list of closed positions for provided list of logins"
it takes 2 arguments , a ReportGroupRequest Object and a list of logins.
I understand what the From and To properties are of the ReportGroupRequest object, but the Name eludes me, I guessed it was perhaps a name of the group for the list of logins, but the method returns the trade list even when Name is an random string. Do you have any more info on this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is just a label. It is not the group name. Go to the manager terminal and click on the "Reports" tab, you can see that while choosing the list of accounts you should put a label to this report.This name is stored for future use. Please check these screenshots. 
[Reports label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnG7i.png) and [Reports list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b15YO.png)"

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation also states  that it should be name of Group. However the only impact I've noticed is that Name will be recorded in MT4 Journal.